# Kotlin API. Как правильно выполнить запрос и разместить в ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Пытаюсь получить по [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow) название вопроса и количество его оценок. Приложение не запускается с таким кодом. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

```
package com.example.test

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ListView
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listview = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)

        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com/").build()

        val service = retrofit.create(StackExchangeService::class.java)

        val repos = service.GetQuestions("stackoverflow")

        val Final = arrayOf(
            repos
        )

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Final)

        listview.adapter = adapter
    }


}
interface StackExchangeService {
    @GET("2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow")
    fun GetQuestions(@Query("stackoverflow") stackoverflow: String) : retrofit2.Call<Question>
}

data class Question (
    @SerializedName("title") val Title: String,
    @SerializedName("score") val Score: Int
)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class com.example.test.Question.
  Tried:
   * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
   * retrofit2.OptionalConverterFactory
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:349)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:311)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:68)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: а где ошибка возникает, приведите Exception

Comment: @Komdosh Пишет "Test (название проекта) keeps stopping".

Comment: не, что пишет LogCat а не телефон

Comment: @Komdosh Виноват, первый день использую Android Studio и Kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343183/retrofit-could-not-locate-converter-for-class-crashing-app

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли выполнить запрос `execute`

```
val repos = service.GetQuestions("stackoverflow").execute()

val Final = arrayOf(
    repos
)

val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Final)
```

Comment: Все равно не запускается.